# How Do I Remove A Subfolder Using Htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

I am trying to remove `/view` from `example.com/businesses/view` so you can go to `example.com/businesses` and it works correctly. Here's what's in my htaccess already:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I plan to do this to multiple directories, so how would I go about that?

Comment: I have posted the answer to your first question below. Can you be more specific about what you mean when you write "I plan to do this in multiple directories" - what is "this", explicitly?

Comment: Is it literally just the URL `example.com/businesses/view`, or do you have URLs such as `example.com/businesses/view/<something>` that also need to be rewritten?

Answer (score 1):

In `example.com/businesses/.htaccess`

write the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^view$ http://example.com/businesses [R=301]
```

Comment: I would assume that you still need to _internally rewrite_ back to the "real" URL?